# search box creation in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

this is my coding for search box in my database but when i run it it shows the error Notice: Undefined variable: searching in /opt/lampp/htdocs/1234.php on line 15
then i i type anything in my search box 
it says
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.3 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7

```
  <html>
  <h2>Search</h2> 
  <form name="search" method="post" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>">
  Seach for: <input type="text" name="find" /> in 
  <Select NAME="field">
  <Option VALUE="fname">diseasename</option>
  <Option VALUE="lname">genename</option>
  </Select>
  <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
  <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
  </form>
  </html>
  <?php 
  //This is only displayed if they have submitted the form 
  if ($searching =="yes") 
  { 
  echo "<h2>Results</h2><p>"; 

  //If they did not enter a search term we give them an error 
  if ($find == "") 
  { 
  echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term"; 
  exit; 
  } 

  // Otherwise we connect to our Database 
  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "****") or die(mysql_error()); 
  mysql_select_db("missensencemuttation") or die(mysql_error()); 

  // We preform a bit of filtering 
  $find = strtoupper($find); 
  $find = strip_tags($find); 
  $find = trim ($find); 

  //Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified 
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE upper($field) LIKE'%$find%'"); 

  //And we display the results 
  while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
  { 
  echo $result['fname']; 
  echo " "; 
  echo $result['lname']; 
  echo "<br>"; 
  echo $result['info']; 
  echo "<br>"; 
  echo "<br>"; 
  } 

  //This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little message explaining that 
  $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); 
  if ($anymatches == 0) 
  { 
  echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
  } 

  //And we remind them what they searched for 
  echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$find; 
  } 
  ?>
```

i dont know what i did wrong in my script. and i am a beginner in php and i am using internet reference for gaining knowledge in php.can one correct this script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like below:

```
extract($_POST);
 if ($searching =="yes")
```

Comment: thanks suresh but when i click the search button this what it shows Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.3 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7

Answer (score 0):

`$searching` is not defined at this moment in the script. I think you mean `$_POST['searching']`.

Add an `if (isset($_POST['searching'])) { //old if }` around the comparison to be sure that `$_POST['searching']` is set and replace `$searching` with `$_POST['searching']`

EDIT: Replace `$PHP_SELF` with `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` , this could help you out.

Comment: After changing to $_server['php_self'] it's in the home page it self

Comment: Then change it to the file you want to send the data. For example `action="search_results.php"`. For now, it sends the data to the current file again.